# PHP Ajax $_POST empty randomly

Tags: php, ajax, post

I encounter a strange occurrence with posting information through Ajax. The script is nothing complex

```
$.post('somefile.php?arg1=somearg&ar2=somearg', {
   somearg: variable,
   ...
}, function(response){});
```

The weird part is when clicking the save button for 1st and 2nd time, the server throws and error that `$_POST` is empty. But when clicking for 3rd and 4th time, it works, without modifying anything on the page.

I know about the php config post_max_size or upload_max_size, it's not a problem and the data is very few.

Please help.

Comment: $.post('1.php?arg1=somearg&ar2=somearg', { data:'example' }, function(response){}); it should work

Comment: Yes I know it works. It normally works but for some reason it doesn't sometime. Do you think it's a packet lost problem?

Comment: are you talking about "arg1=somearg" , well this are GET params huh

Comment: GET param in url + POST param as data in 2nd argument

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try:

```
    jQuery('#loader').show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: yourURL,
        data: {somearg: variable, id: variable2}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        jQuery('#loader').hide();
    });
```

Comment: The javascript is correct and can't be wrong. $.post is the shorthand of $.ajax type POST

Answer (score 0):

You're actually sending your data with get method using `$.post`

```
             $.post('somefile.php?arg1=somearg&ar2=somearg', {
  // These are request parameters  ^            ^
  // and you'll find them in $_GET
             }, function(response){});
```

In order to post them pass them as the second argument of $.post

eg

```
$.post('somefile.php','arg1=somearg&ar2=somearg',function(response){});
```

or

```
$.post('somefile.php',{arg1:'somearg',ar2:'somearg'},function(response){});
```

Comment: It's possible to add paramater in GET and POST at the same time. As said, it's working for the 3rd-4th time but for some reason the 1st time became empty